# How to pass credentials for ApiClient generated by openapi-maven-generator-plugin?

Tags: java, openapi, openapi-generator-maven-plugin, apiclient

I am using `openapi-generator-maven-plugin` to generate an api client from an existing yaml specification [file](https://sharetext.me/hpbcftqae8) in a Java and SpringBoot project .

The API endpoint are protected by Basic HTTP Security scheme (username and password) this way :

```
securitySchemes:
    BasicAuth:
        type: http
        scheme: basic
```

The generated client (`UsersApi` in my case) comes with an `ApiClient` class which will use a `RestTemplate` to perform all the REST calls.

Is there a way to pass the credentials to `ApiClient` so I will be able to reach the external API.

Comment: Please describe which language and generator you are using. That info is necessary for someone to be able to answer you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that I found is to inject 2 beans of type `UsersApi` and `ApiClient` this way :

```
@Configuration
public class ApiClientCustomConfig {

    @Value("${api.credentials.username}")
    private String username;

    @Value("${api.credentials.password}")
    private String password;


    @Bean
    @Qualifier("usersApi")
    public UsersApi usersApi(RestTemplate restTemplate) {
        return new UsersApi(apiClient(restTemplate));
    }

    @Bean
    public ApiClient apiClient(RestTemplate restTemplate) {
        ApiClient apiClient = new ApiClient(restTemplate);
        apiClient.setUsername(username);
        apiClient.setPassword(password);
        return apiClient;
    }
}
```